# Getting the result of several PhP generated checkboxes and displaying only the checked ones underneath

Tags: php, jquery

please excuse my lack of understanding but I am new to PhP.
I have been told this is a simple task to do, but it is only simple when you know how and I simply don't know how.

Basically I have a series of checkboxes generated for items within a simple SQL database. Here is the PhP code:

```
      <select id="multi-select1" multiple="multiple">
            <?php
                //The query asking from our database
                $areaCodeSQL = "SELECT ac.Number AS `AreaCode`, ac.Name AS `AreaName`
                                FROM `AreaCodes` ac";                                                               //SQL query: From the table 'AreaCodes' select 'Number' and put into 'AreaCode', select Name and put into 'AreaName'

                $areaCodeResults = $conn->query($areaCodeSQL);                                                      // put results of SQL query into this variable

                if ($areaCodeResults->num_rows > 0) {                                                               // if num_rows(from $results) is greater than 0, then do this:
                    // output data of each row
                                foreach($areaCodeResults as $areaCodeResult)                                        //for each item in $areCodeResults do this:
                                    {
                                        $areaNameAndCode =  $areaCodeResult['AreaCode'] ." ". $areaCodeResult['AreaName'];  //get AreaCode and AreaName from query result and concat them
                                        $areaName = $areaCodeResult['AreaName'];                                    // get AreaName
                                        $areaCode = $areaCodeResult['AreaCode'];                                    //get AreaCode

                                        ?><option class="menuoption1" name="menuAreaCode" value="<?php echo $areaCode ?>"><?php echo $areaNameAndCode; ?></option><?php  //Create this option element populated with query result variables
                                    }
                }                    
            ?>
        </select>
```

Now I believe I can write a jQuery script like this to show the $areaCode variable in a  called "showResults":

```
 <script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("showResults").text = "<?php echo $areaCode ?>";
    }

    $("menuoption1").each(myFunction());

</script>
```

But it doesn't and I don't know why. Could someone help?

Comment: your selector is wrong. it should be: `$(".menuoption1")` - the `.` is used as prefix so jquery and the DOM knows it's a class-name.

Comment: ... and your myFunction() call will replace text in showResults with only the last value of $areaCode fetched by PHP. As mentionned by Joachim Schirrmacher, you're mixing server-side and client-side.

Comment: Did one of the answers below help? Then please mark it or tell us, what's missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use PHP code in JavaScript. The first is executed on the server, the second (in this case) in the browser.

I suppose you want to show the selected area code in a DOM element with the Id "showResults" (which could be a `<div>`).

You should then register an event handler on change of the select box:

```
$("#multi-select1").on("change", function () {
    $("#showResults").text($(this).val());
});
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/sqo9x42k/

Comment: good answer, also @Liam wrap your <select> tag in `if ($areaCodeResults->num_rows > 0)` , to be avoid creating empty select list

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're jQuery selectors aren't correct. Change

```
$("menuoption1").each(myFunction());
```

to

```
$(".menuoption1").each(myFunction());
```

Note the "."

More information about selectors: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: yeah - just like i said in my comment. but if this is the only problem in OP's code, I'd have no lunch today.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to display the selected options using jQuery, you could use this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menuoption1 option:selected").each(myFunction);
});
function myFunction() {
    $("#showResults").append($(this).val() + '<br>');
}
</script>
<form>
<select name="zob" class="menuoption1" multiple>
<option value="234">uyt</option>
<option value="422" selected>qdwd</option>
<option value="2">iyti</option>
<option value="345" selected>tbb</option>
</select>
</form>
```

See jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ahh02dsv/